# Newbie in port forwarding

Tags: networking, openstack, iptables, virtualbox-networking

I have an Ubuntu Server 14.04 running VirtualBox with some machines. These machines are OpenStack Fuel installed and I cannot change the NIC interfaces infra ( two hostonly and one NAT ).

One of these machines is running the Fuel Control panel, but accessible only by one of the hostonly interfaces ( 10.20.0.2 ).

My home network is 192.168.25.x. The host machine ( Ubuntu ) external is 192.168.25.25.

Now I have a Windows machine in my home network and need to access the Fuel panel running in the VM (IP 10.20.0.2).

What I need is forward the incomming from hardware 192.168.25.25 interface to the virtualbox hostonly 10.20.0.X VM interface to reach the IP 10.20.0.2.

I'm a very newbie in iptables and afraid to mess my hardly installed environment (thanks God is working until now). I've made a dd from dev/sda1 to cover my back but if you gus help me with this all will be easy and I can avoid to recover all stuff.

This is my host ifconfig showing all interfaces:

```
root@AKRAB:~# ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Loopback Local
          inet end.: 127.0.0.1  Masc:255.0.0.0
          endereço inet6: ::1/128 Escopo:Máquina
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Métrica:1
          pacotes RX:19685 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 quadro:0
          Pacotes TX:19685 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 portadora:0
          colisões:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:7674590 (7.6 MB) TX bytes:7674590 (7.6 MB)

vboxnet0  Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 0a:00:27:00:00:00
          inet end.: 10.20.0.1  Bcast:10.20.0.255  Masc:255.255.255.0
          endereço inet6: fe80::800:27ff:fe00:0/64 Escopo:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          pacotes RX:0 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 quadro:0
          Pacotes TX:167 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 portadora:0
          colisões:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:22260 (22.2 KB)

vboxnet1  Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 0a:00:27:00:00:01
          inet end.: 172.16.0.254  Bcast:172.16.0.255  Masc:255.255.255.0
          endereço inet6: fe80::800:27ff:fe00:1/64 Escopo:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          pacotes RX:0 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 quadro:0
          Pacotes TX:437 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 portadora:0
          colisões:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:137886 (137.8 KB)

vboxnet2  Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 0a:00:27:00:00:02
          inet end.: 172.16.1.1  Bcast:172.16.1.255  Masc:255.255.255.0
          endereço inet6: fe80::800:27ff:fe00:2/64 Escopo:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          pacotes RX:0 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 quadro:0
          Pacotes TX:464 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 portadora:0
          colisões:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:150336 (150.3 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 00:13:46:94:18:c1
          inet end.: 192.168.25.25  Bcast:192.168.25.255  Masc:255.255.255.0
          endereço inet6: fe80::213:46ff:fe94:18c1/64 Escopo:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          pacotes RX:2354945 erros:0 descartados:4 excesso:0 quadro:0
          Pacotes TX:1237088 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 portadora:0
          colisões:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:3455421823 (3.4 GB) TX bytes:103231994 (103.2 MB)

root@AKRAB:~#
```

You can see the wlan0 external interface (my home network) and the vboxnet0 hiding the network I want to go to ( 10.20.0.2 ).

All these addresses are static including the target. The port number I want to reach in the VM is 8000.

Comment: Solved here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299459/newbie-in-port-forwarding